# EXM ribbon does not contain 'Open Manager' button

Tags: exm

Running Sitecore 8.2 rev.161221 and EXM 3.4.1 rev. 170105.

The 'Email' ribbon appears on Manager Root item but contains only "Save" and 'Test connection' buttons.

Contextual ribbon in Core DB has two elements: Manager-Open and Server-Test connection

Any ideas why 'Open' button is not shown and how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Every ribbon button is associated with a [`Command`](https://trayek.wordpress.com/tag/commands/) which determines if the button is visible or not. Check the `QueryState` method of the `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Commands.OpenManager, Sitecore.EmailCampaign` class which is bound to the `Open` button.

According to the current implementation, the button should be hidden if:
1. The `/sitecore/system/Modules/Speak/EmailCampaign` item is missing in the content database
2. The URL parameter `mod_link` is not provided

Comment: Sergey is right, but "/sitecore/system/Modules/Speak/EmailCampaign" doesn't and shouldn't exist in 3.4.1. The correct path is "/sitecore/system/Modules/E-mail Campaign Manager". So if you need the button you will have to override the OpenManager yourself.